# How to change width and height of a view programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView in an adapter. I want to set its `layout_width` and `layout_height` programmatically. I have tried a couple of things, but nothing seems to be working. I also later set two constraints for the ImageView.

What I've tried (I do all of this in the constructor for my ViewHolder for the adapter):

```java
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams((int) (imageView.getWidth() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO),
                                                            (int) (imageView.getHeight() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO)));
```

```java
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = (int) (imageView.getWidth() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO);
layoutParams.height = (int) (imageView.getHeight() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

```java
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) (imageView.getWidth() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO);
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (imageView.getHeight() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO);
imageView.requestLayout();
```

I've also tried attaching `OnGlobalLayoutListener`:

```java
imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    imageView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams((int) (imageView.getWidth() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO),
                                                                                (int) (imageView.getHeight() * MainActivity.SCREEN_SIZE_RATIO)));
                    imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

                    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
                    constraintSet.clone(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.donor_planter);
                    constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.top_guideline_image_view, ConstraintSet.TOP);
                    constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.left_guideline_image_view, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
                    constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
                }
            });
```

How I set the constraints:

```java
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.constraint_layout);
            ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
            constraintSet.clone(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.donor_planter);
            constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, R.id.top_guideline_image_view, ConstraintSet.TOP);
            constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.left_guideline_image_view, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
            constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout);
```

I've read a lot on StackOverflow about this, but I can't seem to be able to change the ImageView's width and height. By the way, I am using [this library](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView) for my ImageView (CircularImageView).

Comment: Do not set new `LayoutParams` get the current `LayoutParams` and modify width and height on it . Also debug the value of `imageView.getWidth()` and `imageView.getHeight()` .

Answer (score 0):

it's not the best way to do this but you can make your image view wrapContent and scale your image using BitMapFactory.option(if your image is bit map other wise there is many more ways to scale the image) and control the size of imageView with scaling the image it self